# Using IOTAComponent at runtime

Tags: delphi, runtime, focus, toolsapi

How can I use IOTAComponent in runtime? I need some methods to use in similar mode at runtime that I saw working at design time.

Comment: IOTAComponent is an OTAPI interface and thus only valid inside an IDE plugin.

Comment: The OpenTools API only runs inside the IDE itself, and as such is not available at runtime. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? There may be another solution.